# Multiple regexpr in one string in R

Tags: regex, r

So I have a really long string and I want to work with multiple matches. I can only seem to get the first position of the first match using `regexpr`. How can I get multiple positions (more matches) back within the same string?

I am looking for a specific string in html source code. The titel of an auction (which is between html tags). It prooves kind of difficult to find:

So far I use this:

```
locationstart <- gregexpr("<span class=\"location-name\">", URL)[[1]]+28
locationend <- regexpr("<", substring(URL, locationstart[1], locationend[1] + 100))
substring(URL, locationstart[1], locationstart[1] + locationend - 2)
```

That is, I look for a part that comes before a title, then I capture that place, from there on look for a "<" indicating that the title ended. I'm open for more specific suggestions.

Comment: Can you post your regular expression?

Comment: `?gregexpr` should do it.

Comment: @SimonO101, I thought it meant `global`...!?!

Comment: @DavidStarkey added the info.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `gregexpr` allows for multiple matches.

```
> x <- c("only one match", "match1 and match2", "none here")
> m <- gregexpr("match[0-9]*", x)
> m
[[1]]
[1] 10
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 5
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1]  1 12
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 6 6
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE

[[3]]
[1] -1
attr(,"match.length")
[1] -1
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

and if you're looking to extract the match you can use `regmatches` to do that for you.

```
> regmatches(x, m)
[[1]]
[1] "match"

[[2]]
[1] "match1" "match2"

[[3]]
character(0)
```

Comment: Amazing. Exactly what I was looking for, and more (the addition of regmatches). Also funny I was just one letter off...

Answer (score 3):

`gregexpr` and `regmatches` as suggested in Dason's answer allow extracting  multiple instance of a regex pattern in a string.  Furthermore this solution has the advantage of relying exclusively on the `{base}` package of R rather than requiring an additional package.

Never the less, I'd like to suggest an alternative solution based on the [stringr package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html).  In general, this package makes it easier to work with character strings by providing most of the functionality of the various string-support functions of base R (not just the regex-related functions), with a set of functions intuitively named and offering a consistent API.  Indeed stringr functions not merely *replace* base R functions, but in many cases introduce additional features; for example the regex-related functions of stringr are vectorized for both the string *and* the pattern.

Specifically for the question of extracting multiple patterns in a long string, either `str_extract_all` and `str_match_all` can be used as shown below. Depending on the fact that the input is a single string or a vector of it, the logic can be adapted, using list/matrix subscripts, `unlist` or other approaches like `lapply`, `sapply` etc.  The point is that the stringr functions return structures that can be used to access just what we want.

```
# simulate html input. (Using bogus html tags to mark the target texts; the demo works
# the same for actual html patterns, the regular expression is just a bit more complex.
htmlInput <- paste("Lorem ipsum dolor<blah>MATCH_ONE<blah> sit amet, purus",
                 "sollicitudin<blah>MATCH2<blah>mauris, <blah>MATCH Nr 3<blah>vitae donec",
                 "risus ipsum, aenean quis, sapien",
                 "in lorem, condimentum ornare viverra",
                 "suscipit <blah>LAST MATCH<blah> ipsum eget ac. Non senectus",
                 "dolor mauris tellus, dui leo purus varius")

# str_extract() may need a bit of extra work to remove the leading and trailing parts
str_extract_all(htmlInput, "(<blah>)([^<]+)<")
# [[1]]
# [1] "<blah>MATCH_ONE<"  "<blah>MATCH2<"     "<blah>MATCH Nr 3<" "<blah>LAST MATCH<"

str_match_all(htmlInput,  "<blah>([^<]+)<")[[1]][, 2]
# [1] "MATCH_ONE"  "MATCH2"     "MATCH Nr 3" "LAST MATCH"
```